# TableView内のセルにTextFieldを配置し値を取得・表示させたい

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

TableView内のセルにTextFieldを配置し、パスワード変更画面のような画面を作成したいのですが、初心者のためうまく作成することができません。

記載したソースコードは下記のとおりですが、シュミレータで起動するとうまく動作しません。

下記の画像のとおり、各セルを選択した際に表示が意図しない動きとなってしまします。

期待する動作としては、各セルを選択した際に、TextFieldがフォーカス状態となる状態を期待しております。

ChangePasswordViewController.swift

```
 class ChangePasswordViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    //データ
    var dataInSection = [["現在のパスワード"],["新しいパスワード","パスワードを確認"]]
    //セクション
    var sectionIndex:[String] = ["",""]

    //データを返す
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PasswordCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChangePasswordTableViewCell
        var section = dataInSection[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel?.text = section[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    //データの個数を返す
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return dataInSection[section].count
    }

    //セクション名を返す
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> String?{
        return sectionIndex[section]
    }

    //セクションの個数を返す
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionIndex.count
    }

    // Cell が選択された場合
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PasswordCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChangePasswordTableViewCell
       cell.becomeFirstResponder()

    }
}
```

ChangePasswordTableViewCell.swift

```
class ChangePasswordTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

■シュミレータでの表示時
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■シュミレータで各セルを選択時
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Cell が選択された場合
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PasswordCell", for:indexPath as IndexPath) as! ChangePasswordTableViewCell
   cell.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

このメソッドの`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:〜`が間違いです。メソッド`dequeueReusableCell(〜)`は、`UITableViewDataSource`のメソッド`func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`だけで用いるものと理解してください。
もうひとつ。`becomeFirstResponder()`を送るオブジェクトは、セルではなく、テキストフィールドです。
改善したコードはこうなります。

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ChangePasswordTableViewCell {
        cell.passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: @nagonsoftware様、早速のご回答ありがとうございます。変更してみたところ、上記の「シュミレータで各セルを選択時」の状態は解消され期待どおりの表示となりました。ただ、今度は一番はじめの「現在のパスワード」のセルに文字を入力後、次のセルに移動したところ、「現在のパスワード」に入力した文字列が表示されなくなるという事象が発生しております。「現在のパスワード」セルにフォーカスすると入力された文字は表示されるのですが、フォーカスが外れると文字が表示されなくなるようです。何かコードが不足しているのでしょうか？お手数ですが、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 追加の質問は、質問文本文を編集して、内容を追加するか、新規に質問を立ててください。「何か‌​コードが不足している」というよりは、大量にコードが不足しているといったほうが妥当ではあります。むしろ、基本デザインを変更したほうがいいでしょう。

Comment: @nagonsoftware様、ご連絡ありがとうございます。もう少し自分なりに調査し、検討したいと思います。ご回答・ご指摘ありがとうございました。